# How to change icon at mouseover

Tags: image, mouse

I just added a image on html like this.

```
<img src="Your image address" width="500" height="500">
```

But i want to add mouse over means when mouse curser came on image then image should change, What code i use here. Thanks

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Answer (score 0):

File Hierarchy: Vidzpra/index.html and Vidzpra/images has two images black.jpg and yellow.jpg
Here's the code (HTML with internal javascript) to change image on mouse over:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>onMouserOver Img change</title>

<script>
    function changeImg(el){
        el.src  = "images/yellow.jpg";
    }

    function fixImg(el){
        el.src = "images/black.jpg";
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <img onmouseover="changeImg(this)" onmouseout="fixImg(this)" border="0" src="images/black.jpg" alt="" align="middle" >
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```